# Can gulp receive a string as input instead of file?

Tags: node.js, email, gulp, zurb-foundation

I generate html strings from Python, which are inputs to `Foundation for Email`. (My Python function takes a `Foundation for Email` template and populates it with user data for each user).

My Node server is supposed to receive this html strings, and for each of them, compile it with `Foundation for Email` which runs `gulp` to pick up files in a designated directory and, and for each of them produce an inlined and minified html file.

My Python server should receive this html either via reading file or via api call, and send emails.

I'm thinking about what's the best way to do pass the html to `Foundation for Email` (which runs `gulp`) and pass its output back to a Python server.

I was thinking if I should pass the html string through an API call to a Node server, and passing output from Node server to Python through an API call to Python server, but I am not sure if this is possible or recommended in `gulp`.

Can I do it, and is it a good way to do this? Or should I create html files in the designated path, compile the files, and then use the output files to send emails?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `gulp-file` module (https://github.com/alexmingoia/gulp-file) - this allows you to make a stream of vinyl file(s) (like `gulp.src` does) from strings / buffers which you can pipe as usual.

---

**Sample Code**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var file = require('gulp-file')

gulp.task('test', function() {
    return file([{
        name: 'sample.txt',
        source: 'Hello Mars'  
    }, {
        name: 'sample1.txt',
        source: 'Hello World'  
    }], { src: true })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output'))
});
```